# Thinkpad W530 replacement

Tags: laptop, processor

I am looking for a laptop to replace my W530 thinkpad (from 2012). Here is what I like in the W530:

- matte IPS screen
- good (backlighted) keyboard with key travel of 2.5mm
- keyboard without numpad (I don't like laptop keyboard with numpads because this makes the keyboard offcentric which feels not ergonomical for me)
- good pointing stick with three mechanical mouse keys (I use only the pointing stick and no touchpad)
- no sharp edge at the front of the palm rest
- LAN port without adapter
- works well with linux

The screen size should be 15 or 16 inch.

Since I feel that the ergonomical requirements above are very restrictive I don't want to impose any internal hardware requirements except that it should be a notable performance upgrade to the W530 and should an have M2 or PCI SSD option.

Since I like to buy refurbished devices, you could mention models introduced from 2016 and later.

What I don't need is:

- a DVD/CD drive
- a CAD aimed graphics adapter (like in my case a quadro)

I prefer build in ports (USB, DP OR HDMI, LAN) over carrying a dongle.

The thickness and weight of the W530 is ok for me, no need for an ultra slim design, but I wouldn't complain if the new model would be a bit lighter.

Regarding the screen: The screen of the W530 is not bright enough for outdoor use, so max. brightness of the new model could be a bit better. But it is also important do dim it to a very low brightness to work in a dark room. If possible the dimming shouldn't use PWM.

---

**Update**: Today, over a year since the initial posting of this question, I broke the LCD panel of my W530. Now I am thinking about whether to replace the panel or to buy a new laptop according to the above requirements.

However I want it to be significantly faster, in particular in compiling complex LaTeX documents. As a rule of thumb, if I find a configuration which reduces the compilation times of LaTeX documents by a factor of 1/2 or better and which doesn't introduce too much drawbacks compared to the W530 (see above) I tend to buy a new/refurbished one. Otherwise I tend to replace the panel of the W530.

LaTeX doesn't work parallel so the number of CPU's doesn't really help. However a [high clock](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103565/tips-for-choosing-hardware-for-best-latex-compile-performance) speed helps and (at least I think so) also the [number of instructions per cycle](https://superuser.com/questions/543702/why-are-newer-generations-of-processors-faster-at-the-same-clock-speed) or per second (IPS). For comparison my current CPU in my W530 is a i7-3520M CPU @ 2.90GHz (4 MB L3). However for LaTeX compilation I don't know many [good benchmarks](https://mips.complang.tuwien.ac.at/franz/latex-bench). Also I don't have a source which compares the IPS of the relevant mobile CPUs (compared to my current one).

Maybe I could accept a bit less key travel if it feels still good. Maybe I would also go with a 14 inch screen if I don't find a good 15 inch model and everything else seems to be good.

Comment: Have you had a look at the new X1 models? I also have a w530 but sine I bought a X1 I mainly use the w530 as a desktop replacement (docking with 2x4K screens).

Comment: Yes I looked at the X1 models. But they reduced the key travel from 2,5 to 1,8 mm and then to 1,5 mm on the newest models (as far as I know). But why don't you use the X1 with a dock instead of the W530?

Comment: Yeah the newer X1 might have lower key travel. I have a 4th gen. X1 and the revamped W530 (32 Gb RAM and SSD caddy) is more suitable as a desktop replacement.